# Website in separate browser instance in IOS

Tags: ios, web-browsing, web-browser, sandbox

In IOS, adding a website to the home screen in Safari essentially produces a Safari bookmark on the home screen. When clicking on such an icon, the website is displayed in Safari.

Is there some way to start a separate browser instance when clicking on such a "home screen bookmark", i.e., one which does not share state with the regular Safari instance. This would make it possible to delete state (cookies, website data etc.) of one instance without affecting the other. In addition, both instances would be isolated from each other.

Is this possible by some means?

Comment: So - if you could bookmark something to open in private browsing mode - is that what you seek?

Comment: That would be an option, i.e., regardless of the whether or not private mode is currently active in Safari, whenever you click on a home screen bookmark, it is opened in a new window in private mode. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  Currently, Home Screen bookmarks open the same instance of Safari.